# What are sequences?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What are sequences? How do we denote the numbers inside them?

I know that in terms of computer science, a sequence of items is an array.

Answer (score 2):

A sequence is a function from a subset of the set of integers to a set S.
We use the notation $a_n$ to denote the image of the integer n.

Let Z be the set of integers.

A = [1, ..., n] where n is an integer.

f: A $\rightarrow$ S

i $\rightarrow$ $a_i$

1 $\rightarrow$ $a_1$

A geometric sequence, also called a geometric progression, is a sequence of the form:

a, ar, a$r^{2}$, … , $a^{n}$

where the initial term a and the common factor r are real numbers.

The arithmetic sequence, also called on arithmetic progression, is a
sequence of the form:

a, a+r, … a+mr

where the initial term a and the common difference r are real numbers.